# Disabling/Making read only all combobox in one column in datagrid

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

My grid is getting bound correctly all I have to do is disable or make it readonly all the combobox contained in the Column2 based on any condition from code behind. suppose after the grid is rendered we get 10 rows containing this comboxbox. I have to disable the combobox column in all these 10 rows.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value1}" Header="Column1" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Column2">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyComboItemSource}" >                                       
                </ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a bool property in the Code-Behind and bind to the isEnabled property of the combobox in the xaml.

Code-Behind

```
private bool _Disable;

        public bool Disable
        {
            get { return _Disable; }
            set
            {
                _Disable= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Disable");
            }
        }
```

Xaml

```
<ComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding Disable,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyComboItemSource}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Converter for the property IsEnabled in the combobox.

Something like

```
<ComboBox IsEnabled ={Binding Path=XXXX, Converter = {StaticResource MyConverter}} .... />
```

MyConverter will chech the property you want and retrieve false or true. 
Something like this:

```
 public class MyConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(value!=null)
{
     if((int) value==1)
return true;
else return false;
}

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```